# how to figure out which radio button was selected using jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp

i have two radiobuttons in my application, one is meterid with with combobox and another is consumername with textbox . now the problem is whenever i am selecting the radio button the result is coming correct only but i am unable to findout that which radio button i have selected.

```
My application includes the following code:


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%
Connection con;
String sqlQuery="";
Statement st;
ResultSet rs=null;
%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Meter Search
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<style>
td{FONT: 13px Arial,sans-serif;}
th{FONT:bold 13px Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#153e7e}
input{FONT: 13px Arial,sans-serif;border: solid 1;}
select{font: 13px Arial,sans-serif}
#button{cursor:hand}
A:hover {COLOR: red}</style>




</head>

<body onload ="noback();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">

<br><br>

<form action="./metersearchsuper.jsp" method="post" name="search">
<table align="left" width="40%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#f8f8ff" bordercolor="#333366" >
  <tbody><tr>
    <th colspan="6"  width ="40%" >Search options</th></tr>



<tr><td  width="15%" class="options0" id="tdSearchBy" colspan="5">

<input name="r1" value="MeterID" onclick="searchOptions(0)" type="radio"><font size="4">Meter ID</font></td>

<%
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/suwatermeter","root","sumith");
    sqlQuery="select distinct Meterid from Meter_List";
    st=con.createStatement();

     rs=st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
%>


<td  width="20%" class="options0" colspan="5"><select style="WIDTH: 150px" selected="true" name="meterid" id="meter_id" onChange="this.form.submit()">
<option>Select Meter ID</option>
<% while(rs.next()) {%>
<option value="<%=rs.getInt("MeterID")%>"><%=rs.getInt("MeterID")%></option>

<% } 

rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();
%>

</select>

</td></tr>

<tr><td class="options1" id="tdSearchBy" colspan="5">

<input name="r1" value="ConsumerName"  onclick="searchOptions(1)" type="radio"><font size="3">Consumer Name</font>
</td>
<td><input name="cnsearch" style="WIDTH: 150px"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<tbody> 
<tr><td style="height: 50px; border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);" colspan="4" align="center">

<input name="bSearch" value="Search" style="width: 80px; HEIGHT: 34px; border: 1px solid rgb(13, 31, 78);" onclick="return checkInput()" type="submit">

</td></tr>


  </tbody></table>

<%

try{


    String meterid =request.getParameter("meterid");

    String cnsearch=request.getParameter("cnsearch");
    String r1=request.getParameter("r1");
    String flag="";
    int mid;

    String ConsumerName;

    int SNo=1;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/suwatermeter","root","sumith");
    st=con.createStatement();
   %>
    <input type="hidden" id="Hmeter_id" value="<%=meterid%>">


<%

if(r1.equals("MeterID"))
{
    rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Meter_List where Meterid="+meterid);
    flag="false";
}

if(r1.equals("ConsumerName"))
{
    rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Meter_List where Consumername='"+cnsearch+"'");
    flag="false";
}
if(flag.equals("false"))
{%><br><br><br>

 <table width="100%" height="20%">

 <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

<%
boolean mycolor=true;
int tHeading=0;  //0 means false

if(meterid != null && cnsearch != null )

    tHeading=0;

//else if(getZoneName !=null || !getZoneName.equals("") || !getZoneName.isEmpty())

  // { 
    //tHeading=1;
  // }

while(rs.next()){
String checkdate="";
SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
checkdate=df.format(rs.getDate("Date"));

if(tHeading==0)
    {%>
        <table  border="0" style="" width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
        <th>S No</th>
        <th>Meter ID</th>
        <th>Consumer ID</th>
        <th>Consumer Name</th>
        <th>Reading</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Sub Zone</th>
        <th>Zone</th>
                <%tHeading=1;

      }

 if(mycolor==true)
 {%>
        <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><%=SNo%></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><a href="meteridinfosuper.jsp?mid=<%=rs.getInt("meterid")%>
&Consumerid=<%=rs.getInt("Consumerid")%>&Consumername=<%=rs.getString("Consumername")%>&Subzone=<%=rs.getString("Subzone")%>&Zone=<%=rs.getString("Zone")%>">
    <%=rs.getInt("Meterid")%></a></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><%=rs.getInt("Consumerid")%></td>
    <td  align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><%=rs.getString("Consumername")%></td>
    <td  align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><%=rs.getInt("LastReading")%></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><%=checkdate%></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><%=rs.getTime("Time")%></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><%=rs.getString("Status")%></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><%=rs.getString("Subzone")%></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><%=rs.getString("zone")%></td>
        </tr><%
        mycolor=false;
}
else
{%>   <!--ceefff-->
    <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ceefff"><%=SNo%></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ceefff"><a href="meteridinfosuper.jsp?mid=<%=rs.getInt("meterid")%>
&Consumerid=<%=rs.getInt("Consumerid")%>&Consumername=<%=rs.getString("Consumername")%>&Subzone=<%=rs.getString("Subzone")%>&Zone=<%=rs.getString("Zone")%>">
    <%=rs.getInt("Meterid")%></a></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ceefff"><%=rs.getInt("Consumerid")%></td>
    <td  align="center" bgcolor="#ceefff"><%=rs.getString("Consumername")%></td>
    <td  align="center" bgcolor="#ceefff"><%=rs.getInt("LastReading")%></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ceefff"><%=checkdate%></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ceefff"><%=rs.getTime("Time")%></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ceefff"><%=rs.getString("Status")%></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ceefff"><%=rs.getString("Subzone")%></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ceefff"><%=rs.getString("zone")%></td>
        </tr><%     
        mycolor=true;
}

SNo++;
}

}
rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();
} 

catch(Exception e){}

%>
<script>

    document.getElementById("meter_id").value=document.getElementById("Hmeter_id").value;
</script>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you only have to read the `r1` value in `metersearchsuper.jsp` it will be `MeterID` or `ConsumerName` as result.

```
String selected = request.getAttribute("r1");
```

Comment: thanks for reply actually myproblem is in myapplication 2 radio buttons are there called meterid and consumername. if i am selecting the consumername radio button the result is displaying but after getting the result the radio button is restting it means i am unable to see that which radio button i have selected.

Comment: To find the problem, we need to know that is doing the JS function searchOptions(1) if it is updading DOM, this is normal that values are reset.